# Making an icon bar for android home screen widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to build a Android note taking application and widget. I have the application figured out, and currently I'm in the process of building a home screen widget for the app. How can I implement an icon bar at the top to launch other apps/activities from similar what you see in the Google Keep or OneNote widget?

[image]

Comment: We need to see some code. Read this sscce.org